# duplicate box missing in old post

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

This [duplicated question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/421794/908879) was closed because being a duplicate, however, the dup box is missing (there are *manually added links*<sup>**1**</sup> by a Mod though).

Why is the duplicate box missing in this old post?

<sub>**1** [related post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128040/should-i-rollback-a-manually-edited-possible-duplicate-box) that shows the community reaction of manually adding dup links in posts.</sub>

Comment: Probably because that question was closed as a duplicate before the box got automatically added.

Comment: @TheEstablishment that is one of my theories too (but I want to remove all doubt), anyway, I am sure in a future others will have this same question, so it is worth to create this post

Comment: BTW, I made a [SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/64380/duplicates-that-are-missing-the-possible-duplicate-bit) to find posts like this. Suggested edits to add the links in (usually found in the comments) have been met with mixed approval/rejection votes, so I stopped doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heh...

If you look a little closer, you'll see it was also closed by *one* user, who isn't (and wasn't then) a moderator. And that I'd edited in those links a day prior to it being closed. Things were pretty different in early January of '09...

As [The Establishment theorizes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132405/duplicate-box-missing-in-old-post#comment366242_132405), there was no automated system for adding those links back then. We edited them in by hand (usually *before* the question was closed, so that folks could find them quickly) and if it was re-opened later, edited them back out.

<sup><sub>Oh, and I wasn't a mod then. Strictly-speaking, [I'm still not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-managers-and-what-do-they-do).</sub></sup>

Comment: did you get a notification somehow or it was pure coincidence?, I am impressed how you found this question so quickly :)

Comment: It popped up in the list of meta questions when I checked it before bed ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The first "insert duplicate link" revision made by Community bot was first introduced in May 20<sup>th</sup> 2009 in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887552/reflection-effective-awesome-necessary-uses), you can see it logged [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity&sort=revisions&page=1396). (Oh, and [quite buggy](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/887552/4) at first :))

The [feature change log](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) we got here on Meta only starts at October that year, but the feature was [announced on the blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/linking-duplicate-questions/):

> We tried to look at the existing way the community was dealing with duplicate questions and streamline it into as few steps as possible.

...So when the question you saw was closed that feature simply didn't exist yet like Cody said in a comment.

Comment: If you want more evidence that May 20th was the date, you can find the announcement here: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/linking-duplicate-questions/

Comment: @Shog9 nice, was looking for such thing. Want to add it to your answer and I'll delete my own?

Comment: Naw, this is fine - I was headed to bed last night, and too lazy to edit it in.